# JQuery delegate not working for certain inputs

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to use JQuery to automatically sum inputs in a table where rows are added dynamically. $().delegate and $().live do not seem to work if the selector contains an input with a name with [ ]. The same selector works with bind.

Here is a sample code :

```
<div id="area">
  <input name="x[]"/>
  <input name="x[]"/>
  <input name="x[]"/>
  <input name="x[]"/>
</div>

$("#area").delegate("input[name='x\\[\\]']", 'change', function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

[Sample code](http://jsbin.com/eyoro3/2/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me using this : http://jsbin.com/eyoro3/3/edit

```
$("#area").delegate("input[name='x\[\]']", 'change', function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Apparently, [ ] shouldn't be escaped, unlike for bind. "input[name='x[]']" works too. Thanks !